Why does Teensy 4.0 read of resistor divider change at 1.9V
I have a Teensy 4.0 and I'm trying to read the voltage of a 2S battery. I'm using a resistor divider with Rhigh 33k and Rlow 10k.
The ratio I get is not quite right, even after calibrating that out there is a strange jump in the readings at around 1.9V. There's hysteresis to it too. After the reading jumps, it stays high until I lower the input voltage below a certain point.
I tried adding a 100nf cap parallel with Rlow, to reduce the output impedance, but the effect is still there.

Downvotes but no comments... Real brave guys.

Answering myself, since this took me a LONG time to figure out:
The digital inputs on the Teensy stay active even when the pin is being used for analog reads.
When the voltage passes the logic threshold, the input buffer state changes and the input impedance changes slightly.
If your analog signal has a high output impedance (7.7k in my case) this change in current into the GPIO will cause a significant shift in the reading.
This is a major gotcha when using the ADC on the teensy IMO. I'm not sure if the same is true on other arduinos like the UNO.
In any case, the solution is to simply add pinMode(<pin>, INPUT_DISABLE) for each analog pin in your setup function.
Credit for the solution goes to this guy: https://forum.pjrc.com/index.php?threads/teensy-4-0-4-1-web-pages-need-a-warning-about-input_disable-on-analog-inputs.69671/
